# Solution Ordinary Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Find the distance which an object moves in time $t$ if it starts from rest and has an acceleration $\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}=ge^{-kt}$.
>
> Show that for small $t$ the result is approx $1.10$, and for very large $t$ the velocity $\frac{dx}{dt}$ is approx contrast

I started with integrating $\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}=ge^{-kt}$ with respect to $t$ and got $\frac{dx}{dt}=-\frac{g}{k}\cdot \frac{1}{e^{kt}}+C$

Taking $lim_{t \to \infty}-\frac{g}{k}\cdot \frac{1}{e^{kt}}+C=-\frac{g}{k}\cdot 0+C=C$ so the second condition is met.

Now I integrate once more with respect to $t$ $\int \frac{dx}{dt} -\frac{g}{k}\cdot \frac{1}{e^{kt}}+C=\frac{g}{k^2}\cdot \frac{1}{e^{kt}}+C\cdot t+C$

But the solution is $x=\frac{1}{k}gt+\frac{g}{k^2}(e^{-kt}-1)$

Comment: The limits of integration (or equivalently, the initial conditions) are important here. You haven't used the "starts from rest" condition anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

In your question:

> it starts from rest

gives the initial conditions: $x(0)=0$ and $x'(0)=0$

use these .....( and note that the two constant of integration are different: $C_1$ and $C_2$).

Answer (score 1):

We start with
$$
\ddot{x} = g \, e^{-kt}
$$
and integrate. assuming our initial time is $t_0 = 0$:
$$
\dot{x}(t) - \dot{x}(0) 
= g \, \int\limits_{0}^t e^{-k \tau} \, d\tau
= g \left[
-\frac{1}{k} \, e^{-k \tau}
\right]_{\tau = 0}^{\tau = t}
= g \left(
-\frac{1}{k} \, e^{-k t} + \frac{1}{k}
\right) 
= \frac{g}{k} \left(1 - e^{-kt}\right)
$$
We apply the initial condition $\dot{x}(0) = 0$ and integrate once more:
$$
x(t) - x(0) =
\frac{g}{k} \int\limits_0^t
\left(1 - e^{-k\tau}\right) \, d\tau
= \frac{g}{k} \left[
\tau + \frac{1}{k} e^{-k\tau}
\right]_{\tau=0}^{\tau=t}
= \frac{g}{k} \left(
t + \frac{1}{k} e^{-kt} - \frac{1}{k}
\right)
$$
Applying the initial condition $x(0) = 0$ we get
$$
x(t) = \frac{g}{k} t + \frac{g}{k^2} \left(
e^{-kt} - 1
\right)
$$

Comment: How did we get $-\frac{1}{k}$ with the minus sign in $\frac{g}{k} \left(
t + \frac{1}{k} e^{-kt} - \frac{1}{k}
\right)$?

Comment: That is the antiderivative (the term in square brackets) evaluated at the lower bound $\tau = 0$, which gives $1/k$, which has to be subtracted.